# i try to get reponse headers but can't get anything

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

When into filter, I want get the reponse headers to find if response is gzipped, but can't get anything.

I try to `getHeaders()` from response, but it is null.

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        String method = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst("method");

        String info = String.format("Method:{%s} Host:{%s} Path:{%s} Query:{%s} token:{%s}",
                exchange.getRequest().getMethod().name(),
                exchange.getRequest().getURI().getHost(),
                exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath(),
                method,
                exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(Constants.AUTHORIZE_TOKEN));
        exchange.getAttributes().put(START_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());

        ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();
        exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Encoding");
//that result is null so i can't get Content-Encoding
```

I expect the result is gzip, but the actual result is null.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no response object because routing is not processed.

If you want to check response, you have to do that after `NettyRoutingFilter.filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain)`.

You can do like below.

```java
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange).thenEmpty(
        Mono.defer(() -> {
            ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();
            originalResponse.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Encoding");
            // your logic ...
            return Mono.empty();
        })
    );
}
```